# How to change time periods from character to numeric

Tags: r, time

I've got a dataset with a character variable with time periods, written like this:

```
16 sec
1 min, 35 sec
45 sec
3 min, 42 sec
```

and so on.

What is the fastest way to change it into a numeric variable in *seconds* or *minutes*?

I can't just delete words `min` and `sec` with `regexr`, because there are a lot of meanings of the variable only in seconds, without minutes and I don't know how to separete them from minutes after imputation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are min and sec the only character strings? And does min always come before sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(time.string=c("16 sec", 
                        "1 min, 35 sec", 
                        "45 sec", 
                        "3 min, 42 sec"))
```

Now, you can convert the time strings into **seconds** by converting `min` into `*60`, `,` into `+`, and removing `sec`.

```
df$time.expr <- gsub(", ", "+", gsub(" min", "*60", gsub(" sec", "", df$time.string)))
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
#     time.expr
#1          16 
#2     1*60+35 
#3          45 
#4     3*60+42
```

Now, you evaluate the resulting expressions like this:

```
df$time.int <- sapply(parse(text=time.expr), eval)
```

Which will give you this out output:

```
#      time.string time.int
#1          16 sec       16
#2   1 min, 35 sec       95
#3          45 sec       45
#4   3 min, 42 sec      222
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really helps)

Answer (score 4):

Using the `lubridate` package

```
x <- c("16 sec", "1 min, 35 sec", "45 sec", "3 min, 42 sec")

library(lubridate)
as.numeric(as.duration(x))
# [1]  16  95  45 222
```